# new xcode 4 project using tab bar controller

Tags: xcode4

completely new project  using tab bar  controller,  no file is modified.  when I tried to use map view in firstview.xib file  and run the application . It show Thread 1:  Program received signal: "SIGABRT".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an exception log in console see that.And then try to remove the cause.

To view console check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377309/xcode-4-how-do-you-view-the-console)