# XCode equivalent for command window in Visual studio.net

Tags: visual-studio, xcode, debugging, command-window

Is there any equivalent in XCode for the command window in VisualStudio, in a way that lets me modify variables values while in debug mode (standing on a breakpoint), by evaluating expression, but not in read-only mode like the console.

Is there any?

Comment: try with debugging console

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377309/xcode-4-how-do-you-view-the-console

Comment: i knew about the console, but didn't know about the "set expression"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console is not read-only if you're referring to the gdb session. You can use the 'set' command to set the values of variables in gdb. Try 'help set variable' for more info.

Comment: I've been using console for months now, i thought i could only use set for "set unwindonsign on" and "set call-po-at-unsafe-times" :D thanks a lot that's great news