# How to get old console log

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, console

I wan to use the console log to resolve a bug of my application. So I view the device console log using Xcode. Problem is console log has clear the earlier logs and it shows only limited amount of log entries. Is there a way to access old log entries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377309/xcode-4-how-do-you-view-the-console

Comment: Actually bug happened in the application installed in an iPad. So I wanted to access the iPad's console log using Xcode's organizer. I select the device and clicked on the console but it has limited amount of log entries.

Comment: @iPatel You have added a answer to a problem of viewing console in xCode. Im having a different kind of problem. Problem is device console save limited amount of log entries (ex. last 1000 entries) in the memory.

Comment: @nath have you got any solution to get old device logs? I need console log of 12 hours before but from all means, I am only able to get log of latest run.

Comment: @AkbariDipali No I couldn't find a solution. So I redirect all logs to a file so that I can see it when I needed. So I can resolve any issues come in future

Answer (score 11):

I found two ways to do this.

1. Generate a sysdiagnose and AirDrop it to your computer. The sysdiagnose tarball contains a bundle called system_logs.logarchive which can be opened with Console.

- On the device, press both volume buttons and the lock button simultaneously. Release after 1 second. You should feel the device vibrate. Note that holding down the buttons for longer than that will bring up the emergency call screen.
- On the device, go to Settings -> Privacy -> Analytics -> Analytics Data.
- Scroll down until you see sysdiagnose_<current date>. Select it, and tap the send button. Tap on your computer name to send the log via AirDrop.
- On your computer, accept the AirDropped item. This will be a tar.gz file
- Open the tar.gz file and decompress. Inside, you will see system_logs.logarchive
- Double-click system_logs.logarchive. This should open the bundle in Console.

2. When the device is connected to your Mac over USB, you can gather logs from it using the `log` tool. From Terminal, run `log collect --device --output logs.logarchive`. Then, open logs.logarchive in Console.

Note that Console will only show the last 5 minutes of messages by default. You can change this near the bottom of the window:

[image: The "Showing" drop-down list]

Comment: Can you explain how to do it in detail, please?

Comment: @allenlinli I added more detailed instructions to my answer.

Comment: Need to release buttons after around half a second, before the emergency call screen appears.