# How can you show the debugger console in "xcode 6"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

In Xcode 5 you could show the bottom view and show the debugger console. But in xcode 6 I'm getting no data when running on the simulator. What gives?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Go to XCode -> Preferences -> Behaviors -> Select “Starts” in Running -> Select “Show” debugger With “Variables & Console View”

[image]

than select the "Hide or show the Debug area" Button

[image]

and Now click on Small Arrow Button

[image]

i think it might be helpful in your case.
For more info you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377309/xcode-4-how-do-you-view-the-console).

Answer (score 8):

Nothing of the above worked for me, but Rob´s answer helped me to find the solution.
I had to activate the console in View > Debug Area > Activate Console (shift-command-C)

Answer (score 4):

You can click on small triangle at the bottom to see the console.

[image: screenshot illustrating this]

You can also use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Bhumit's answer, you can also choose View > Debug Area > Show Debug Area from the menu bar.

The default keyboard shortcut to show or hide the debug area is <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> (shift-command-Y).